# Broken gtk theme?

Tags: gtk

All my menus are highlighted like in the attached image.

[image]

I asked around and someone told me my gtk theme might be broken. However, I have no clue how to fix it. This occurs on my system menus, DE changer in the login menu, and most other programs.

Comment: Do you have the Gnome 3 (both, testing)  PPAs activated? if you do, an update might just have happened, and yes the GTK Theme needs to be updated to reflect the changes

Comment: Both PPAs were activated. I'm not sure how to update a GTK theme though.

Comment: Yeah, happened to me too you''l have to use the gnome packages from Ubuntu or wait for the author to update the theme.

Answer (score 2):

It's problem with unity-settings-daemon / gnome-settings-daemon. You can report a bug [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bugs).

- On **Ubuntu 14.04 and newer** following command should fix problem *(run it from a Terminal)*:

  ```
  sudo killall -9 unity-settings-daemon && unity-settings-daemon & disown
  ```
- On **Ubuntu older than 14.04** tou can try *(run it from a Terminal)*:

  ```
  sudo killall -9 gnome-settings-daemon && gnome-settings-daemon & disown
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was struggling with this for a month it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, an update brakes compatibility with Themes.

So you'll have to remove the Gnome 3 Team PPA and the Ricotz testing PPA then downgrade the packages to the Ubuntu version.

Install ppa -purge to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for Unity I fixed this problem by deleting `~/.config/gtk-3.0` that I had left over from some earlier [tweaking](http://binbashblog.blogspot.de/2011/10/manually-change-gtk3-theme-in-xubuntu.html) when still using 12.04.

With Xfce, I had this problem when using Settings / Appearance / ambiance-xfce-lxde theme that I got from http://www.ravefinity.com/p/ambiance-radiance-for-xfce-lxde.html

For Xfce, I fixed this by making a new theme with everything else from Ambiance, but the gtk-2.0 folder from ambiance-xfce-lxde:

```
cd /usr/share/themes
sudo cp -r Ambiance MyAmbiance
sudo cp -r ambiance-xfce-lxde/gtk-2.0/ MyAmbiance/
```

and then selecting MyAmbiance from Settings / Appearance.

Edit: Now on xubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 16.10, and this trick still helps to fix some appearance issues when using the above theme.